# secure APP_KEY to further strengthen Encryption in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security, encryption

I am storing sensitive user data in my application.

**Crypt** facade class of *PHP Laravel* is being used to *encrypt/decrypt* sensitive data.

**APP_KEY** is at config folder

Database being used is MySql. Encrypted data is stored at DB

I want to further strengthen my security at application.

*Need suggestions to hide the **APP_KEY** from project, or have it in some encrypted format.*

Aim is to keep it secure from getting leaked, so that even the developers do not have access to it .

---

Any other tip to further strengthen my encryption is also welcome !

Comment: If you are using CI/CD you can use something like Amazon Parameter store to store it and write into the `.env` file in build time

Comment: If you encrypt the encryption key, where will you store the encryption key that encrypts the encryption key? :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky Any suggestion to hide it atleast at PROD env !